# How to cast an int unique_ptr into a void unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a function that looks like

```
void *func(){
    int *a = new int;
    *a = 1;

    void *b = a;
    return b;
}
```

and in my main function I can use it like

```
int *test = reinterpret_cast<int *>(func());
std::cout << test[0] << std::endl;
delete test;
```

and it will print the correct result. Lets say I want to use unique_ptr for my function so it becomes

```
std::unique_ptr<void> func(){
    std::unique_ptr<int> a(new int);
    *a = 1;

    std::unique_ptr<void> b = a; // does not compile
    return b;
}
```

It throws a compilation error

```
error: conversion from ‘std::unique_ptr<int>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::unique_ptr<void>’ requested
```

What should I do to make unique_ptr work in this scenario?

Comment: What exactly do you think the semantics of `unique_ptr<void>` are?

Comment: How is `delete` supposed to work on an unknown type when it comes time for the `unique_ptr` to clean up?

Comment: Also why would you return a `void*` from the function if the calling code is just going to cast it back to `int*` anyway?

Comment: This does not make sense. Ditch the the `void*` stuff and get your types straight.

Comment: Just....... no.

Comment: @Brian I'm guessing this is a simplification for demonstration purposes. Think of how `void*` is used in functions like `qsort()` -- it's not converted back to the real type until you call the comparison function.

Comment: The reason I have to do this `void *` thing is I have to use a legacy function from a library that is expecting an input of a function pointer that has return type `void *`. Just wondering if I can use C++11 code or am I forced to use the old C++98 raw pointers...

Comment: Then you'd best manage the ownership through `unique_ptr<int>` and convert the managed `int*` to `void*` when you pass it to the legacy API.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Great point on it's impossible to delete `unique_ptr`, is there any `std::move` tricks to work around this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `unique_ptr` holds a *deleter* that is responsible for executing a `delete`-expression (or `delete[]`-expression) on the pointer, when the lifetime of the `unique_ptr` ends.

But the expression `delete p` when `p` is a `void*`, is invalid.

So the default functionality of `unique_ptr` does not support `void*`. I am not sure if it is explicitly forbidden or not to have a `unique_ptr<void>`. But if it's not forbidden, then trying to define a custom deleter to do this work, would not be smart.

Instead fix the design.

Don't throw away the type information in the first place.

Comment: You can just define an unique pointer to void as long as you provide your custom deleter (that is trivial to write indeed). I've seen it used in type-erased context, as an example.

Comment: @skypjack: It's not very likely that the OP is doing type erasure. I think that's entirely the wrong advice. As stated in the answer.

Comment: _So the default functionality of unique_ptr does not support void*. [...]. But if it's not forbidden, then trying to define a custom deleter to do this work, would not be smart_. This suffices for a downvote. I agree on the fact that the question probably arises from a design issue, but it doesn't justify a misleading information. I would rather explain that `void` is supported, show how it works and say that this is not the case to use it. By saying that _it is a wild beast that sooner or later will bite you_ you are not giving the OP and future readers the right information. My two cents.

Comment: skypjack's attempt at placing words in my mouth means he can be safely ignored about anything. Anyway, it's not true as he writes that "void is supported". It's merely not forbidden, but there is no support, in particular no deleter.

Comment: I just quoted your answer actually. Your attitude sounds like you are not here to give the best answer and discuss with the others on how to improve it. So, reputation mining is the purpose? Ok, got it.

Comment: Above are a bunch of new Trump-like lies from skypjack. The first: "I just quoted your answer actually." That is not true. http://i.imgur.com/xwbiMMv.png

Comment: _Trump-like_. :-D ... Don't want to argue. Anyway, downvote explained. That's all.

Comment: Regarding the "fix the design" statement. Consider the case where you receive octets from a wire. After the header, you have a variable payload. That can easily be done through void* casting. I see no way of doing that without template explosion.

Comment: @Makketronix: Let's first be clear that this is not the OP's case; at least it doesn't square with the presented example code. I think my first choice for representing a sequence of bytes would be `vector<byte>`. However, Google has used just `string`. I do not know the rationale of their choice. It has a cost in that a `string` is by convention, on modern systems, assumed to hold text encoded with some extension of ASCII.